# Magento 2. Log Out the Customer from all other machines

Tags: magento2, customer, login

The customer should be logged out from all other machines at login.

- Is this something that Magento offers?
- How would I achieve this? Some pointers where to start from | Where to look. I'm not expecting someone to provide me with an extension.

Thank you